# How do I write a Mail.app rule to mark messages as read in one mailbox but leave them as unread in my in-box?

Tags: mail.app, mail-rules

I have a Mail.app rule that copies certain incoming messages into an archive mailbox. I'd like those messages to be marked as read in the archive mailbox but remain unread in my in-box until I actually read them. I tried adding "Mark as Read" to the copy rule but that marks the message as read in both the archive mailbox and my in-box, so I never have any unread messages in my in-box. Any ideas?

Comment: Depends on your mail provider and if you use IMAP or POP to fetch your mails

Answer (score 1):

It seems Mail 6.0 in Mountain Lion has fixed this for me. When I have new mail it shows as unread in both my in-box and my archive mailbox. And now, when I read it in my in-box it gets marked as read in both my in-box and my archive mailbox. Chalk one up for Mountain Lion.